# How contrapositive proof works

Tags: logic

To prove $p\rightarrow q$, it suffices to prove $\neg q\rightarrow \neg p$. The reason is if I proved $\neg q\rightarrow \neg p$, that means there is no case where $\neg q$ is true and $\neg p$ is false($q$ is false and $p$ is true.) so when I assume p is true q must be true. Is this how contrapositive proof works?

Comment: You can write out the truth tables for both of these if you really want to convince yourself

Comment: [Here's a useful tool.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(p%E2%86%92q)%E2%86%94(%C2%ACq%E2%86%92%C2%ACp))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one way of putting it. We can make what you're doing here more formal with the concept of [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). We start with $2^2=4$ possible choices of the truth-values of $p,\,q$, each either true or false. You reason that $\neg q\to\neg p$ is telling us we don't keep any of these $4$ cases for which $\neg q$ is true and $\neg p$ is false. In other words, we eliminate exactly $1$ case, the one for which $\neg p\land q$. We then note each of the surviving cases makes $p\to q$ true. In fact, since the remaining cases *and only the remaining cases* do this, $p\to q$ is *equivalent* to $\neg q\to\neg p$, i.e. either statement can prove the other.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed.

Every evaluation that holds $\neg q\to\neg p$ as true and $q$ as false must value $p$ as false (via *modus ponens*).

So any evaluation that holds $\neg q\to\neg p$ as true and $p$ as true therefore must value $q$ as true (because doing otherwise would produce a contradiction).

Thus we deduce that $\neg q\to\neg p$ logically entails $p\to q$.